# Display error or warning message without ApexPages using Global Component

Tags: visualforce, javascript, community, dynamic-visualforce, javascript-remoting

I have a simple form , which has a output panel and pageMessage inside it .

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="errorPanel">
            <apex:message id="msg" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

I have visual force remoting function which returns a json result object containing message, errorCode if there is error, and other key/value parameters. Now once this json object is returned, there is a call back function which must display the error message on the screen if there is an error. How can i display the error message using the global `$Component` syntax? I am trying to set the title of the message as shown below, but I  get this error:
"Cannot set property 'title' of null" .

```
function handleresult (result,event){
if(!result.success){
            //display error message 
            var element =  document.getElementById('{!$Component.errorPanel.msg}');
            element.title = result.message;

            return;
}
```

Please help me out solving this issue??

Comment: Are you missing `!` in `'{$Component.errorPanel.msg}'` or is it a mistake while posting?

Comment: It is a mistake while posting, i am not missing it. I basically want the <apex:pageMessage> to show error message on the page if there is an error. Only that component should be refereshed without using <action:Function>. Hopes this helps

Comment: give an id to the `form` as well and use the full path `!$Component.theForm.errorPanel.msg`. If `form` has parents(other than the `<apex:page>`) give ids for them as well and use the full path

Comment: It is not working , i tried var element =  document.getElementById('{!$Component.formId.errorPanel.msg}'); and if i do console.log(element). It shows null in the inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `<apex:message />` component is nested one, you might need to use more complete path specifier as described in the [documentation here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm).

So try below VF code

```
<apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:outputPanel id="errorPanel">
            <apex:message id="msg" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

And access it in your JS function as below.

```
var element =  document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.errorPanel.msg}');
```

Also note that if your `form` component has any parent components you might need to introduce `id`s for them as well and use that full path in your JS function.